# mysql STATE showing "updating" while INFO showing "DELETE" in Show Full Processlist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

```
--------------------------------------------------------
    | Command   |   Time    |   State       |   Info
--------------------------------------------------------
      Execute   |   24      |   updating    |   DELETE FROM table WHERE account_id=? and date=?
```

How come instead of using UPDATE its using DELETE?

PHP code is this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table(account_id,data,date) VALUES(?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data = VALUES(data)");
            $stmt->bind_param('iss', $account_id,$data,$date);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
```

Comment: it's not. something ELSE is doing that query. maybe if you had a `replace ...` query, you'd see a delete in the process list, but insert/dupe key doesn't delete.

Comment: doesn't make sense, I don't have delete anywhere

Comment: scheduled jobs in mysql? cron? other parallel users?

Comment: I decided to kill the connection and that seems to fix the issue, not sure why though